# Initializing a class when using Generics

Tags: c#, .net

I've a Document class which has two overloads taking one parameter each (String and Stream). Why can't I use the following code to initialize Document class using Generics?

```
    public abstract class PdfDocumentEditBaseService<T> : IDocumentEditService<T>

    public T Rotate(T file, int pageNumber, float angle)
    {
        Document document = new Document(file); // cannot convert from 'T' to 'Stream'
        document.Pages[pageNumber].Rotation = (RotationMode)angle;
        document.SavePage(pageNumber);
        return file;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few suggestions to require T to inherit from Stream.  And that will work.  But, if your T really is always a stream, why not just remove the generic parameter and build that class like this:

```
public abstract class PdfDocumentEditBaseService : IDocumentEditService
{
    public Stream Rotate(Stream file, int pageNumber, float angle)
    {
        Document document = new Document(file); 
        document.Pages[pageNumber].Rotation = (RotationMode)angle;
        document.SavePage(pageNumber);
        return file;
    }
```

Comment: Document class has two overloads taking one parameter each one is Stream and other is String. I want to handle this scenario with Generics.

Comment: Why?  Overloads seems like a better fit here.

Comment: +1 agree generics are not always a fit, overloads do seem to fit nicer here

Answer (score 3):

You can do that if you change your declaration to:

```
public abstract class PdfDocumentEditBaseService<T> : IDocumentEditService<T> where T : Stream
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a [type constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) to your class declaration:

```
public abstract class PdfDocumentEditBaseService<T> : IDocumentEditService<T>
                                            where T : Stream
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the constructor for the Document class requires an argument that is a Stream or derived from Stream.  As the code is written there is no guarantee that T will be a Stream.

If you add a type constraint to the class declaration this should work:

```
public abstract class PdfDocumentEditBaseService<T> : IDocumentEditService<T> where T : Stream
```